# How to set a Field value as a plain Object via Reflection

Tags: java, reflection, field

I have a model class:

```
public class Model {

@KeyDefinition("name")
private String mName;

@KeyDefinition("age")
private int mAge;

public Model(){

}
```

And I have a `List<Object>`(Values) & a `List<String>` (Keys) that I handle through the `map` method:

```
public <T> T map(Class<T> cls){
    T instance;
    try {
        instance = cls.newInstance();
        for(Field field: cls.getDeclaredFields()){
            if(field.isAnnotationPresent(KeyDefinition.class)){
                KeyDefinition annotation = field.getAnnotation(KeyDefinition.class);
                for(int i = 0; i < mKeys.size(); i++){
                    if(annotation.value().equals(mKeys.get(i))){
                        field.setAccessible(true);
                        field.set(instance, mValues.get(i));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
    return instance;
}
```

So if the value of the annotations is equals to a "Key" item from a list, then I grab the Object in the corresponding position and set the field's value to that.

But, when I reaches the `mAge` field I get the following message:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set int field Model.mAge to java.lang.String
at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167)
at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171)
at sun.reflect.UnsafeIntegerFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeIntegerFieldAccessorImpl.java:98)
```

What I have possibly done wrong?

Comment: Please post your main class which create a List<Object> values and List<String> keys.

Comment: To set an `int` value you need an `Integer`, reflections won't automatically know how to turn a `String` into an `int` value.

Answer (score 1):

The error is pretty clear. Age is an int and you're trying to assign an Object to it through reflection. It's unsafe because the Object could be anything. You'll either need to a) determine the field type in your loop and convert Objects to whatever type accordingly, or b) give yourself a setter that can accept an Object, and go through setters rather than fields, or c) make the age field be a generic Object, which of course is not ideal.

Another strategy you could use is to make some object to whatever converter class and specify it as a parameter to your annotation, then use that to convert.

Sorry about lack of examples, on phone.

Comment: How can I determine the field type in your loop and convert Objects to whatever type accordingly (your a) way) ?

Comment: @Kanellis if field.gettype() == integer.class then set field as an int, or whatever.